# How to modify the value of "by ____" in a facebook post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When my website es shared on facebook there is a legend on the bottom of post, with the url and the author of the website-app. In example, this image from the fb open graph documentation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qXL3.png
in that example how do i change the value of "BOILER ROOM"?

Comment: That is an open graph post. So read up on Open graph and how to publish actions

Comment: thank you @WizKid  wouldnt post this question if i havent already read the whole thing. I cant find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/#attachments

The 'By ' string in your screenshot is a property of the object - in your own stories you can specify which object properties should be displayed with your stories